# Why can't change folder name in foreach

Tags: c#

For renaming the folder's name I used the below code.
When I debugged it for each return a right value and it recognize folders with the pattern
But it cant rename folders name!

```
string[] myDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(myRootPath, "*", 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories);

string findFolderNamePattern = @"((?i)domain|.com(?-i))";
string replacement = "";

foreach (var myDirectory in myDirectories)
{
    Regex.Replace(myDirectory, findFolderNamePattern, replacement);
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to assign the return value of `Replace` to something? I don't see any renaming going on in your code. What error are you getting and on which line?

Comment: You cant alter loop variable.

Comment: `myDirectory = Regex.Replace(...`

Comment: Side note: `.` means *any character* in regular expressions. Do you mean `@"((?i)domain|\.com(?-i))";`? (*escaped* `.`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you seem to be changing the string and not renaming the folder anywhere. You'll need to go through and rename the identified folder as such:

```
foreach(var myDirectory in myDirectories)
{
    new DirectoryInfo(myDirectory).MoveTo(Regex.Replace(myDirectory, findFolderNamePattern, replacement));
}
```

That should rename each folder as it identifies it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two thing to consider:

1. Iteration variable can't be changed.
2. Regex.Replace method takes three parameters and returns:

> A new string that is identical to the input string,
>   except that the replacement string takes the place of each matched
>   string. If pattern is not matched in the current instance, the method
>   returns the current instance unchanged.

You can have a look at it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_).

Based on these the following code finds matched folder names and renames them.

```
      string findFolderNamePattern = @"((?i)domain|.com(?-i))";
      string replacement = "";    
      foreach (var myDirectory in myDirectories)
      {
          string newDirName = Regex.Replace(myDirectory, findFolderNamePattern, replacement);
          Directory.Move(myDirectory, newDirName);
      }
```

Comment: maybe you're still working on it, but this answer could be improved if you replaced "my shot" with a brief description of what you're doing and how it fixes the problem

Comment: Do you know why I get this error? `msg: Could not find a part of the path.
ie: 
src: mscorlib
 stk:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalMove(String sourceDirName, String destDirName, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.Move(String sourceDirName, String destDirName)`

Comment: @D.JCode It is thrown when a directory path doesn't exist. You can check the values of sourceDirName and destDirName variables while debugging and figure out the missing path.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop and define the variable inside it if you wanted to update your array.

```
for (int x=0; x < myDirectories.Count; x++)
{
    replacement = Regex.Replace(myDirectories[x], findFolderNamePattern);
    myDirectories[x] = replacement;  //this requires a for loop
}
```

Or forget about the temp var:

```
for (int x=0; x < myDirectories.Count; x++)
{
    myDirectories[x] = Regex.Replace(myDirectories[x], findFolderNamePattern);
}
```

If you don't want to use a for loop:

```
int x = 0;
foreach (var myDirectory in myDirectories.ToList())
{
   replacement = Regex.Replace(myDirectory, findFolderNamePattern);
   myDirectories[x] = replacement;  //this requires a for loop
   x++;

}
```

Or, simply do this (as Dan Wilson commented):

```
replacement = Regex.Replace(myDirectories[x], findFolderNamePattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can not alter the loop iterators, you can rather use another array, as the code below shows:

```
public static void Rename(string myRootPath)
    {
        string[] myDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(myRootPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        string[] myDirectoriesModified = new string[myDirectories.Length];

        string findFolderNamePattern = @"((?i)domain|.com(?-i))";
        string replacement = "";

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var myDirectory in myDirectories)
        {
            myDirectoriesModified[i] = Regex.Replace(myDirectory, findFolderNamePattern, replacement);
            i++;
        }
    }
```